# How to restrict a Element with a name getting created to the Model that already have an element with the same name? Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo

```
a = kw.get('a')           #text getting from the user input
models = request.env['htpmodel']
for model in models:
   if str(a) != str(model.name):
        h = model.create({
            'name': a,
        })
```

If the str of user input(a) is not in the model's name needs to be created otherwise duplicate element needs not to be created

Comment: `models` is an empty record, you can't use `name` field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest searching for the record first using the name you are supplied:

```
a = kw.get("a")

models = request.env["htpmodel"]
# search to see if a record with that name already exists
record = models.search([("name", "=", a)], limit=1)

if not record:
    # the record doesn't exist
    h = model.create({
        "name": a,
    })
```

A query to the model would be better practice than to loop through the results.

Let me know if you need anything clarifying,

Thanks,